# I have Nami windows series 140/141, spec: H-R35/H-R50. Does the top portion slide down for cleaning?

Tags: windows

[image]
Has a sliding bar at top on each side. 
Can't tell if top should slide down??

Comment: Doesn't look to me like the top is designed to slide down. When you say there is a "sliding bar at top on each side" what are you referring to? All I see is a plastic stop, to limit upward travel of the lower sash, and the "screw type" sash balance/guide tube for the lower sash.

Comment: A picture of the lower half of the window might also help us determine if this is a double-hung window.